# ML problem in dimensions less than or equal to 6

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

I have a new ML model $F$(in development stage) which I need to test and compare with the state of the art ML models like deep learning. Unfortunately I cannot run my ML model $F$ in higher dimensions, as my computations increase rapidly with number of dimensions. So the highest dimensions I can go is upto $6$. So I cannot really test it on state of the art problems like MNIST etc.,. But I'd like to compare it with other ML models (Neural Nets,etc,) on a problem that is not more than 6 dimensions. So Is there any such ML problem with dimensionality less than or equal to 6?

Comment: The thing is people usually don't usually employ neural nets for such small problems. Perhaps you could try some common pre-processing algorithms such as stacked autoencoders or stacked RBMs, which are routinely used to pre-train deep nets. But then the resulting features would be highly discriminant already, so I'm not sure how fair a comparison like that would be.

Comment: @Firebug : Don't worry, this is just for theoretical research purposes only. Just to study theory of models, rather than prescribing methods for public to use in a practical setup.

Comment: Take it easy, Rajesh.  It's doing nobody any good to attack someone who is trying to provide constructive advice.  Read https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice, cool down a little, and take these comments in the helpful and friendly spirit with which they were written.

Comment: You could also try some toy datasets, like the checkers pattern. Then you could focus on how your algorithm performs in terms other than generalized predictive performance, such as number of iterations, parameters fitted, or time complexity on the size of the problem.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Nowhere I disrespected you, I'm trying to give you constructive inputs. If you don't want people to give you ideas **then why post the question at all**? I prefer to do my work myself instead of employing total strangers on the internet to do it for me, but to each his own. Have a good time :)

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju, please note our [be nice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy & abide by it. Remember that you are asking strangers over the internet to volunteer their time to help you.

Comment: sorry. I Apologize whole heartedly. @FireBug. I agree everyone is free to express their ideas and its all about sharing ideas.

Answer (score 7):

The [UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php) [1] is the first place I look for datasets and dataset related questions.

It turns out that, yes, there are in fact [88 datasets](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html?format=&task=&att=&area=&numAtt=less10&numIns=&type=&sort=nameUp&view=table) listed with fewer than 10 attributes and a good number of these have six or fewer.

Some classic examples include:

1. [Chess (King-Rook vs. King)](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Chess+%28King-Rook+vs.+King%29) - Chess endgame database for White King and Rook against Black King (KRK);
2. [Iris](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris) - Perhaps the best known database to be found in the pattern recognition literature. From Fisher, 1936;
3. [LED Display](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/LED+Display+Domain) (seven binary attributes) - LED displays contain seven light-emitting diodes and emit one of the ten decimal numbers; and
4. [Yeast](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Yeast) (eight attributes) - Predicting the cellular localization sites of proteins.

> [1] Lichman, M. (2013). UCI Machine Learning Repository [http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml]. Irvine, CA: University of California, School of Information and Computer Science.